# Add-Migration not working with MySQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have downloaded Asp.Net MVC 5.x Single page web application from https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates. I'm using MySQL and followed the steps mentioned in link https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/EF-MySql-Integration. But when I run the `Add-Migration` command it gives the error.

**MyCompany.MyProject.Web\Web.Config:**

```
<add name="Default" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;Database=SparTestDb;uid=root;password=root" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

**MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFramework\Migrations\Configuration.cs**

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    ContextKey = "Spar";

    SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
}
```

**Error:**

> PM> Add-Migration "AbpZero_Initial" System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3
>   k)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
>   at Abp.EntityFramework.AbpDbContext.RegisterToChanges()    at
>   Abp.Zero.EntityFramework.AbpZeroDbContext`3..ctor(String
>   nameOrConnectionString)    at
>   MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFramework.SparDbContext..ctor() in
>   C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\MyCompany.MyProject
>   (1)\3.3.0\src\MyCompany.MyProject.EntityFramework\EntityFramework\SparDbContext.cs:line
>   19
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
>   DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   migrationsConfiguration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. PM>

Comment: What is your MySql.Data version ? Try to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.9.11.

Comment: I have 6.10.7 version

Comment: 6.9.11 is working well. Higher versions have problems. So, Try to use nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.9.11. Or if you are using EF Core, you can use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Krishna_K_Systematix  welcome :) added solution as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql.Data version 6.9.11 is working well. Higher versions have problems. So, Try to use [nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.9.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.9.11). Or if you are using EF Core, you can use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I have MySql.Data of version 8.0.26 and MySql.Data.Entitiframework 8.0.26, after debugging to sourcecodes i've found that for local migrations EF tryes to connect using SSL, so in my case helped to turn OFF ssl using connection strin parameter:

`SslMode=none`

Example connection string:

```
"server=localhost;port=3306;user id=root;password=1q2w][=[;database=TmpMigrations;persistsecurityinfo=True;Allow User Variables=True;SslMode=none;"
```